# How do I setup Auto Return URL for a PayPal Buy Button?

Tags: url, button, paypal, return

I am using the html code for a simple Paypal buy button but was wondering if it's possible to setup an auto return url without having to do it through my own Paypal account itself?

I can't do it that way because it is a localhost website (cannot validate a real website) and I'm not creating a button through my selling tools.

```
  <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
                    <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="email@email.com">
                    <!-- Specify a Buy Now button. -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
                    <!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Demo">
                    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="0.01">
                    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
                    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="~/">
                    <!-- Display the payment button. -->
                    <input type="image" name="submit" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
                    <img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif">
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can set your own return URL. [HTML Special Variables](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/?mark=html%20variables). You can add this code to your form.

```html
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://localhost" />
```

In your html you are defining a relative path to your home directory but you will need an HTTP or HTTPS url for it to work. This is because the page that the paypal checkout is on is not in your root directory, so it needs a specific location.